# Android Studio ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-manifest

> ERROR: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0] C:\Users\User.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\856a947c1a9c6ebc4d2fc0c2fb4dbece\firebase-iid-19.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
>       Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
>           or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
>           or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.iid" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

```
    dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' // Google Services plugin
     }

     dependencies {
         // Add the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.1.0'
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

minSdkVersion for firebase library is changed to **API level 16** to align with the [Google Play services distribution policy](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/12/google-play-services-discontinuing.html).

so you have to change your gradle file like

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        ..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error says minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 
In that case:

Just change the `minSdkVersion` in gradle file to 16

Answer (score 0):

The minimum SDK level required to use the [most recently versions](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2019-05-07) of Firebase libraries **is 16**. There is no workaround.

In your `build.gradle` file change the value with:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16  //or higher
        ..
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @RuhulAmin if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

in your **build.gradle** file, please change the version higher than "**minSdkVersion 15**".

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.Demo'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.6"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

and Add gradle :-  `implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'`

Answer (score 0):

Please go to build.gradle(Module.app) and update "minSdkVersion" to 16 or more as below:

defaultConfig {
        .............
        minSdkVersion 21
        ............
    }

or upper then click on "Sync".

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and the solution worked for me as follows:

You have to go to the **build.gradle** file **.. app**
and then to the defaultConfig{ . section
and replace this text

```
minSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
```

with this code

```
minSdkVersion 19
```

then click on "Sync".

---

*Of course, this solution will work with those who work on Platform Flutter , Visual studio code*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).